# Filtering a pandas dataframe comparing two columns

Tags: python, pandas, filter

Consider a dataframe which consists of various columns, but I would want to filter the dataframe by comparing values of two columns. Here below is the sample of dataframe .

```
Machine   Position
  M01         PB0
  M02         PB0
  M03         PB0
  M04         PB0
  M01         PB1
  M02         PB1
  M01         PB1
  M01         PB1
```

Above you can see All machines have Position PB0 but only two machines has both PB0 and PB1, now I would expect maybe a list of machines which has both PB0 and PB1
`machine=['M01','M02']`
One thing to consider is among these two columns there could be many duplicates.

Comment: You wrote below is an expected dataframe but there is none, only the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's define your dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Machine': {0: 'M01',
  1: 'M02',
  2: 'M03',
  3: 'M04',
  4: 'M01',
  5: 'M02',
  6: 'M01',
  7: 'M01'},
 'Position': {0: 'PB0',
  1: 'PB0',
  2: 'PB0',
  3: 'PB0',
  4: 'PB1',
  5: 'PB1',
  6: 'PB1',
  7: 'PB1'}})
```

To get the positions of each machine, regardless of duplicates, we can use:

```
s = df.groupby('Machine')['Position'].apply(set)
```

Which looks like this:

```
Machine
M01    {PB1, PB0}
M02    {PB1, PB0}
M03         {PB0}
M04         {PB0}
Name: Position, dtype: object
```

To get only the machines whose positions include both `PB0` and `PB1` we can use

```
s[s.apply(lambda x: x.issuperset({'PB1','PB0'}))].index
```

which returns

```
Index(['M01', 'M02'], dtype='object', name='Machine')
```

(you can also add a `.to_list()` at the end if you prefer a list to a pd.Index)

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
new_df = df.groupby("machine").count().reset_index()
m = new_df[new_df["Position"]==2]["machine"].tolist()
print(m)
```